# distinct query with lumen and mongodb not working

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel, eloquent

I want to get count of unique value my query is like below,

```
 $query = DB::connection('mongodb')->collection('email_message')
                ->distinct()->select("email_thread_id")
                ->where('email_account_id', (int)$request->email_account_id)
                ->where('status', "Active")->where('folder_id', "=", $folderId);
    $result = $query->count();
```

it's count value should be 9 and I am getting it as 12.

it is not giving me distinct value.
can any one help me to resolve it out?

I have update my mongodb screen shot below, here I have deleted one record , so it will show total 11 records 
[image]

Comment: *"it's count value should be 9 and I am getting it as 12."* - This statement requires **proof**. If you want to say something then you need to provide the means for someone else to [reproduce your results.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). This also ensures you were not actually mistaken and missed something pretty obvious. Read the link and give people something they can reproduce.

Comment: `field` name is missing in `distinct()` which might be the reason for incorrect results.

Answer (score 1):

```
You didn't mention the distinct('FIELD_NAME') field name.

$query = DB::connection('mongodb')->collection('email_message')
            ->distinct('email_thread_id')->select("email_thread_id")
            ->where('email_account_id', (int)$request->email_account_id)
            ->where('status', "Active")->where('folder_id', "=", $folderId);
$result = $query->count();
```

NB:: I have just mention the field name over distinct()

Comment: it is not working, it is still gives me 12, instead of 9

Comment: but I required distinct value of email_thread_id with mongodb

Comment: Please check your DB Record , is there 12 distinct record or 9. It should return proper distinct value.

Comment: there are total 12 records without distinct value, with distinct there are 9 records

Comment: @hetalgohel Can you please send a screeenshot of your record with field name , then i may understand the problem acually

Comment: I have attached screen short in my question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183928/discussion-between-md-jubair-mizan-and-hetal-gohel).